# Does changing MTU need restarting the application?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, mtu

Let us say we have an aerospike cluster running with interface mtu as 1500. If I want to switch to jumbo frames, do I need to restart the aerospike cluster? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about changing heartbeat.mtu in https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/?

This is a dynamic parameter available only in Enterprise edition. You won't need to restart the cluster for changing this dynamic parameter as long as you follow https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/troubleshoot/dynamic_config/index.html#dynamically-change-parameters%2Fconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MTU of the interface to support jumbo frames does not require the restart of any applications.  The packing of packets happens much lower in the stack than applications are concerned with.